# Add theme support for post thumbnail isn't working from theme class

Tags: theme-development

I have a theme class that I bootstrap my theme in and add the theme support but the featured image meta box isn't appearing.

Inside the class file:

```
    class WCS_THEME {
    
        private function __construct() {
            $this->setup_hooks();
        }
    
        // Singleton design code here
    
        protected function setup_hooks() {
            add_action( 'after_theme_setup', [ $this, 'setup_theme' ] );
        }
    
        public function setup_theme() {
            add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
        }
    }

\WCS_THEME\Inc\WCS_THEME::get_instance();
```

Inside functions.php:

```
require WCS_DIR_PATH . '/inc/classes/class-wcs-theme.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

If that's the whole class then you don't have a method called `get_instance`

By the way, even if you had a `get_instance` method, you are calling `get_instance` as a static method, `__construct` gets called only when creating a new instance from the class using the `new` keyword, like this

```
$obj = new WCS_THEME();
```

That's basically it, Going the your class in it's current state, all you need to do is a new instance, as shown in the code above.

Don't forget about the namespace we creating the instance